# recursively combining elements across several arrays of integers in Python

Tags: python, recursion, bit-manipulation, combinations

The problem: given an arbitrary number of arrays of positive integers, find all combinations of their elements, one from each array, such that the numbers' set bits do not overlap (A & B == 0 for every two elements A and B of a resulting combination):

```
[[1, 2, 4], [8, 16]]   =>   [[1, 8], [1, 16], [2, 8], [2, 16], [4, 8], [4, 16]]
[[55, 49, 5, 61], [8, 97], [70, 20, 50]]   =>   [[49, 8, 70], [5, 8, 50]]
[[180, 44], [9, 182], [115, 110]]   =>   []
```

So far I've managed to come up with this code:

```python
from itertools import chain
def find_combos(sets, combo=[], used_bits=0):
    set_idx = len(combo)
    if set_idx == len(sets):
        return [ combo ]
    to_try = filter(lambda n: not n & used_bits, sets[set_idx])
    # return [ c for n in to_try for c in find_combos(sets, combo+[n], used_bits|n) ]
    return list(chain.from_iterable(find_combos(sets, combo+[n], used_bits|n) for n in to_try))
```

Only, I don't particularly like the look of it, what with all the constant unwrapping and rewrapping.
I feel like there must be a more elegant/efficient solution, a clever `itertools` trick maybe. Anyone?

Comment: what does "such that their set bits do not overlap" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `A & B == 0` means that the intersection is empty?

Comment: @cards Sorry, I've reworded the question. The `&` is bitwise.